# Should I use GoogleAuthUtil to call my backend to secure the communication even I don't need to use the logged Google user?

Tags: android, https, google-play, google-oauth, google-play-services

I am writing a game where the user sends his score to a server I maintain.

I want to secure that the score has been submitted from the game app, not from a curl request or other mean of HTTP request not started by the app.

I read [this entry in the Android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) and I thought I needed to implement this, but I'm not sure.

Along with the score, the user will send a player name typed in an EditText as his player name. This means that the users are identified with a name they choose, NOT their Google account username.
Neither the client nor the server need to access the Google user account at any time.

Is this meant to do what I want, or is it used only to guarantee that one HTTP has really been performed from the device of a specific Google user account?

What should I pass as email to the getToken(email, scope) method?

My users won't have an Android AccountManager account.

Answer (score 1):

After more diving I have concluded that:

- The email that GoogleAuthUtil#getToken() expects is the email of the user's Google account. This can be programmatically retrieved via the AccountPicker class. This is explained [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/consume_android).
- I could use this method to authenticate my server calls, but I think that if I do not plan to use the user Google account information and I don't plan to use the Google Cloud endpoints, I could work with something simpler.
  Moreover, If you I used this to authenticate the calls I would depend too much on Google, not being able to release the app in the Amazon market, where the user may not have a Google account (Kindle FIre).